# Rails won't read a link with nokogiri and open-uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, nokogiri, open-uri

I have a controller which gets a url passed as a parameter and I am trying to scrape the entire page at that url. But when I try to read the url I get the following error: `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - www.google.com`

Controller:

```
lass PageScraperController < ApplicationController
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'diffy'
    require 'htmlentities'

    def scrape
    require 'open-uri'
        @url = watched_link_params.to_s
        @url = @url.slice(9..@url.length-3)
        puts "LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOG#{@url}"

        page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@url))
        # coder = HTMLEntities.new
        # encodedHTML = coder.encode(page)
        puts page

     end

    def watched_link_params

        params.require(:default).permit(:url)

    end

end
```

Comment: I think you want `@url = watched_link_params[:url]`. Then you can avoid the mess you are making with converting the hash to a string and then slicing out the part that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def scrape
  @url = watched_link_params[:url]

  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@url))
  puts page
end
```

You will need to pass in the entire url, including the protocol designator; that is to say, you need to use `http://www.google.com` instead of `www.google.com`:

```
>> params = ActionController::Parameters.new(default: {url: 'http://www.google.com'})
>> watched_link_params = params.require(:default).permit(:url)
>> @url = watched_link_params[:url]
"http://www.google.com"
>> page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@url))
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it and I have also removed that mess with the slicing.